# how to get the coordinates for the shaded region when plotting autocorrelation function using "plot_acf" of statsmodels

Tags: python, data-science, statsmodels

I'm trying to get the coordinates of the shaded region for each of the x-ticks from the autocorrelation function's plot. I'm using statsmodels `plot_acf` function.

Below is a sample code,

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

dta = sm.datasets.sunspots.load_pandas().data
dta.index = pd.Index(sm.tsa.datetools.dates_from_range('1700', '2008'))
del dta["YEAR"]
sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(dta.values.squeeze(), lags=40)
plt.show()
```

[image]